# dplyr - including sum across groups data in aggregation

Tags: r, dplyr

with a `df` like below

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(c('A', 'B'),2) , weight = sample(c(40:100), 4))
```

I want to get the percentage weight by name - so I do the following.

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(wt_sum = sum(weight)) %>%
  mutate(wt_perc = wt_sum/sum(wt_sum))
```

Is there a way to get this done in summarise itself following typical `dply` usage patterns?

Comment: You could just do: `W <- sum(df$weight)` and `dg <- df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(wt_per = sum(weight)/W)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to `df$weight` directly then `dplyr` will ignore the grouping, so the following gives you the answer using just `summarise`

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(wt_perc = sum(weight)/sum(df$weight))
```